# Sortable stops working when no elements left in the table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a working sample of a table with draggable rows. I can transfer between the rows, which is nice, but as soon as one table has no children in it, the table becomes unable to accept children.

http://jsfiddle.net/yf47u/264/

HTML

```
            <table id='table-draggable1'>   
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>col1</th>
                    <th>col2</th>  
                    <th>col3</th>  
                    <th>col4</th>  
                </tr>
                </thead>
             <tbody class="connectedSortable">
                <tr>   
                    <td>156</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td>  
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>256</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td> 
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
        </table>
        <table id='table-draggable2'>  
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>COL1</th>  
                    <th>COL2</th>  
                    <th>COL3</th>  
                    <th>COL4</th>  
                </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody class="connectedSortable">
                <tr>   
                    <td>356</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td>  
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>456</td>                                                                                         
                    <td>668</td>                                                              
                    <td>100.95</td> 
                    <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                </tr>  
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "tbody.connectedSortable" )
    .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "tr",
        helper:"clone",
        zIndex: 999990
    })
});
```

Is there a way to make the sortable zone bigger when all the children leave? I want to be able to put new rows into empty tables; also the rows have to be appended inside `<tbody>`

Comment: Possible quick fix: add a field into the table but set `display: none`

Comment: But I can still move things under it, which I don't want. If there is going to be a field at the bottom it needs to stay at the bottom. Is there a way to keep the last field always bottom?

Comment: It seems that jquery's sortable doesn't have a prependTo option. Meaning that newly moved elements will appendTo the end therefore moving existing elements up. The newest moved element will be at the bottom. I think one of those event callbacks is where you should be looking to possibly reorder or prevent the append and prepend instead.

Comment: Just in terms of aesthetics I don't want there to be a moment where the user can put a row underneath the blank row. With the callback I can only imagine the user dropping the row and then things are sorted...but aesthetically this isn't ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the Html and Jquery as seen below, this works fine for me.

**Html**

```
 <table id='table-draggable1' class="connectedSortable">   
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>col1</th>
                        <th>col2</th>  
                        <th>col3</th>  
                        <th>col4</th>  
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                 <tbody >
                    <tr>   
                        <td>156</td>                                                                                         
                        <td>668</td>                                                              
                        <td>100.95</td>  
                        <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>256</td>                                                                                         
                        <td>668</td>                                                              
                        <td>100.95</td> 
                        <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                    </tr>  
                </tbody> 
            </table>

            <table  id='table-draggable2' class="connectedSortable">  
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>COL1</th>  
                        <th>COL2</th>  
                        <th>COL3</th>  
                        <th>COL4</th>  
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <tr>   
                        <td>356</td>                                                                                         
                        <td>668</td>                                                              
                        <td>100.95</td>  
                        <td>1.82</td>                                                                  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>456</td>                                                                                         
                        <td>668</td>                                                              
                        <td>100.95</td> 
                        <td>1.82</td>                                                                
                    </tr>  
                </tbody> 
            </table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#table-draggable1,#table-draggable2" )
        .sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            items: "tbody > tr"
        })
    });
```

**See the Jsfiddle link**

http://jsfiddle.net/yf47u/274/

Comment: This is working for me only if I add `style="min-height: 50px"` to tables. YOu also can make a style like this `table.draggable-zone { min-height: 50px; }`.